# acceptable mod_rewrite friendly-url approach?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I try to rewrite all url's to a single php file, unless the url leads to an existing file because existing files like images should be handled by the server directly. But if someone uses a url that looks like a file, and this file doesn't exist, it should get a 404.

I came up with the following .htaccess file. Is this a valid approach? It will be on a production server this friday so I would like to know for sure that there is no security risk or is a bad practice of some kind.

The first rule should make sure that any url that looks like if a file is being requested will get 404 (only if the file doesn't exist of course).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([-A-z0-9]+)$ - [R=404,L]
```

If above doesn't match, there is a second rule that rewrites all other non existing files  to index.php (like eg /products/23). In this case index.php will handle the rest of the routes.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L]
```

If no rule mathes, it means it is an existing file is found and will be served by apache directly, like existing images and scripts.

Is this a valid approach? Thanks.

EDIT:

a slightly shorter approach with similar result:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([-A-z0-9]+)$ - [R=404,L]

FallbackResource /index.php
```

Seems to work.

Comment: +1 I think this is indeed a valid approach but `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([-A-z0-9]+)$ - [R=404,L]` should be replaced with: `RewriteRule ^.+?\.[^./]+$ - [R=404,L]`

Comment: Thanks! I try to understand your regex. Could you explain it shortly?

Comment: `.+?\.` means match until dot is found (non-greedy) and `[^./]+` means match everything (1 or more length) except dot and slash.

Comment: @anubhava would the `[^./]+` also not mean that his non existing file /product/23 also get a 404 (which he would like to be handled by /index.php) ?

Comment: @Rik No because `[^./]+` is coming after a dot.

Comment: @Sander The FallbackResource is indeed nice (and i would use that) but you will still need a check for /my_bogus_file.html to get a 404. With my `header` solution you could do that in you index.php.

Comment: @Sander Aaah. Now i think i see it. I'm getting my slashes and back-slashes mixed-up (It's late). You are checking for files WITH extension and giving the 404. This works ok. Only /product/mybugus_product gets to index.php without a 404 but perhaps that's not a problem for you.

Comment: @anubhava thanks, I understand now. Couldn't be better....

Comment: @Rik Ja, Het is laat he haha

Answer (score 1):

I would only do your second check (if file exists) and if not, always redirect to your index.php.

There you can do your checks for product etc. and use

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
include('404.html');                  // <----- this is your 404 file
exit();
```

if you want to generate a 404 error.

Comment: Nice approach also! Can you explain why you would choose for your solution? Is it more safe/faster?

Comment: I find it easier. I didn't exactly understand why you would check for the request of a file in your first check. With the `^(.*)\.([-A-z0-9]+)$` you would only check within a sub-directory and not in the root. So /myfile.html does not get a 404. Only /subdir/myfile.html would get a 404. So for all those request in the root you would still need to do a check in your index.php. So why not simplify it and do all your checks and 404 redirects in the index.php with the additional benefit of giving a 404 for non-exisiting products.

Comment: Thank you! In my system root also works... I will always need both, I know. For this situation I want filehandling to be handled as soon as possible and Apache does the job. From there other routing is done by PHP and a illegal routing could also result in a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Comment: That was my first guess also. But I have a images folder and want to get a 404 if someone requests a non existing image like /images/not-a-image.jpg. My code seams to handle that. The rest works similar, but I figured that I don't need the !-d.